# Scaling image with CSS Transition

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, image-scaling

This is how I want to scale my images, [smoothly without any jumps](http://themes.themegoods2.com/keres/gallery-4-columns/).

My attempt does not work like in the gallery above, the image (red square in my case) jumps, [my code](http://www.cssdesk.com/ThGXH):

```css
section {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.701961);
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}

div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 120px;
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;

}

div:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.8);
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div></div>
</section>
```

How to fix this? The red square jumps. Is it possible to scale smoothly with CSS Transition at all like in the gallery in the link at the beginning?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What do you mean by "jumps"? Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/omagwu6h/1/), jumps too?

```css
section {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.701961);
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}

div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 120px;
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
    transition: transform 0.4s;
}

    div:hover {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.8) rotate(0.01deg);
        transform: scale(1.8) rotate(0.01deg);
    }
```

```html
<section>
    <div></div>
</section>
```

Also, you could try the variant with a container for an image (like in the first link of your question).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/o1ztj3o0/1)

```css
.banner {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #dfe2e5;
    background: #000;
    width: 310px;
    height: 150px;
    -webkit-transition: border-color 0.1s;
    transition: border-color 0.1s;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    .banner:hover {
        border-color: #bdc1c5;
    }

    .banner__image-container {
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .banner__image {
        -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
        transition: all 0.4s;
    }

        .banner:hover .banner__image {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.15) rotate(0.01deg);
            transform: scale(1.15) rotate(0.01deg);
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
```

```html
<div class="banner">
    <div class="banner__image-container">
        <img class="banner__image" src="https://picsum.photos/310/150/?image=1022"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It still jumps in my Chrome version (44.0.2403.155 m), on Windows 7. Not always, but if you repeatedly hover - unhover, in some cases it will make a sudden change in dimension. I believe it is a bug in newer Chrome versions.

Comment: @vals maybe. I think it's OK in the first example of the question because an image has a container.

Comment: @vals for example, I did something like that for my company, does it jump too? http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/o1ztj3o0/

Comment: Yes, it jumps, but it is less noticeable because the scale is lower. But I do believe it is a bug, and probably it is not reproducible in other settings

Comment: @Sergey Denisov indeed in the first example of the question an image has a container but does the sole reason of having the container change anything, could you expand on what difference does image having a container bring ? I suppose the problem is Chrome,

Comment: @Piotr when you have a container, you apply `:hover` styles by cascade, like in my example: `.banner:hover .banner__image { ... }`. And a container has `overflow: hidden`. So, real size of your block isn't changing because image scales inside fixed sized container. I think it could fix "jumping". http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/o1ztj3o0/

Comment: Ok, I will give it a shot. and how to apply color change at the same time like in that gallery http://themes.themegoods2.com/keres/gallery-4-columns/ ?

Comment: Sergey Denisov Thanks a lot man the second code you sent me http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/o1ztj3o0/1/ seems to have solved both issues for me in chrome (but maby it is temporary 
that it works without jumps.

Comment: @Piotr thanks. I improved my answer, added the latest code snippet which suits to you.

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes solve strange jumps on transition by adding `rotate(0.01deg)` on the transform property, like so:

```
.element:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5) rotate(0.01deg);
}
```