# How to zoom image on hover with CSS

Tags: css

How can I zoom an image that is inside an div on hover using CSS (zoom only the image, not the div).
See what I'm talking about [here](https://youtu.be/5WRX1gz-K-Q)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033723/scaling-image-with-css-transition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some minor modifications of @tim-klein answer to get effect from video

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 184px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
      transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}

.container:hover img {
      transform: scale(2,2)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish the general idea by using the `:hover` pseudo-class. Note: I didn't go overboard with keeping the `img` centered or using a transition to mimic the slow zoom, however, you could easily add those features if desired.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 184px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container:hover img {
  width: 120%;
  height: 120%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of different ways to tackle this.

**Demo:** https://codepen.io/shanomurphy/pen/BvMrWq?editors=1100

---

### 1. Using `background-image`

**HTML:**

```
<div class="zoom-bg"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.zoom-bg {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.zoom-bg:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('https://placeimg.com/300/200/nature') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.zoom-bg:hover:before {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

---

### 2. Using nested image and `object-fit`

Basically the same as [@Alx Lark's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2505342/alx-lark) answer but adding `object-fit` to maintain the aspect ratio of the image.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="zoom-img">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/200/arch">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.zoom-img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.zoom-img > img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.zoom-img:hover > img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```